# Boto3 and multiprocessing

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, multiprocessing, boto3

I want to implement some code in parallel (using 64 workers). In particular, I want to read objects from an S3 bucket, do some processing, and write them.

Something like:

```
def read_file_from_s3(i):

    j=0

    for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=f'folder_name/'):
    
        if i==j:

            response = obj.get()

            df = pd.read_csv(response['Body'])

            df = df[df['some_col'].isin(some_list)] #this is the processing

            df.to_csv(f's3://some_bucket_name/some_other_folder/file_{i}.csv', 
                      index=False, storage_options = {'key': key, 'secret': secret})
        j+=1

a_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(64)
a_pool.map(read_file_from_s3, list(range(64)))
```

The thing is that, there a lot more than 64 objects in the folder (I don't know how many).
How can I iterate over all objects but still exploit 64 workers?

Answer (score 0):

You can move the iteration logic into the main process that creates the multiprocessing pool, and pass along only the S3 Key to the worker to allow it to get the object.

For instance:

```python
import boto3
import multiprocessing

_bucket=None
def init_read_file_from_s3(bucket_name):
    # Helper to create a S3 resource object for this worker
    global _bucket
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    _bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)

def read_file_from_s3(values):
    # Pull out the data
    i, s3_key = values

    # Perform work on a given S3 Key, use the single S3 bucket object the
    # initializer created before this worker started
    obj = _bucket.Object(s3_key)
    response = obj.get()
    # TODO: Operate on the object here, "i" is a unique ID for this item

    # Inform the caller that we're done with this key
    return s3_key

def main():
    bucket_name = 'example-bucket'
    prefix = 'example/prefix/'

    # Get a s3 resource object to list the objects with
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)

    # Initialize all of the workers with the bucket name so they can create a S3 resource object
    with multiprocessing.Pool(64, initializer=init_read_file_from_s3, initargs=(bucket_name,)) as a_pool:
        # List the objects, and feed each key in turn to a worker
        # Note that the object returned from filter() or all() isn't picklable, so we
        # pass just the string of the S3 key
        for result in a_pool.imap(
            read_file_from_s3, 
            [(i,x.key) for i,x in enumerate(bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix))]):
            
            # Just show the key that was operated on
            print("Done with: " + result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks! Two questions: (1) I got this: `NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials` Where should I locate in the code the my `key` and `secret`? (2) If, after processing, I want to write each object as a CSV file, how can I give them different names, for example `f'file_{objectNumber}'`?

Comment: @qwerty I've updated the answer to include a unique ID with each file.  As for credentials, please see the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html).  I **highly** recommend that instead of hard coding credentials, you use the AWS CLI to store them in a configuration file away from code.